# How to best print output to command window during a loop in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, printing

I have a loop which iterates through a list of ID numbers paired with a given stress value. The code works fine, except there is no guarantee that the lists have identical lengths. I currently have an `if isempty(stress_value)` loop with a `continue` statement if an ID number doesn't have corresponding stress value. All of this takes place in a `for id = 1:num_ids` loop.

I am now trying to print this `id` value (class 'double') to the command line, if it doesn't have an assigned stress value, so if the `isempty` statement is True, prior to continuing out of the loop. As an example, if I set `num_ids` equal to 101, but the list I'm iterating through only has ID values 1-100, I want to output this 101 ID to the command line.

I've tried printing as an error like this:

```
error(['The following ID does not have an assigned stress value: ',id])
```

Here `id` simply prints as `e` however when I try this in the command window, which I don't quite understand. When I run it in the script nothing is printed to the command window.

I have also tried simply adding a display command for the id to the loop as follows, however when I run the code nothing shows up again:

```
disp(id)
```

Sorry for the simple question, but I have not found an effective way to do this yet, and would appreciate your feedback!

Comment: “When I run it in the script nothing is printed to the command window.” How do you run the script? This makes no sense from where I’m sitting. Are you by chance starting a new MATLAB session just to run your script, and exiting that session when it’s done?

Comment: It looks like you're not using the right approach. Please provide a minimal working example so we could answer your question.

Comment: Hello, @Thales answer worked in this case. I hadn't seen that the message formatted as an error terminates the code. The other mistake I made was assuming that display could output concatenated strings as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [fprintf](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html). You can format your output just like you want.

```
for id=1:num_ids
    % do something
    if isempty(stress_value)
        fprintf('The following ID does not have an assigned stress value: %d\n',id)
        continue
    end
    % do something
end
```

The [error](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/error.html) function will stop code execution.

The [display](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/disp.html) function only prints the value of the variable, without printing the variable name.

Comment: If your code had other places where information is written to the screen you can update the `fprintf` statement to be `fprintf ( 2, 'The following .....'`  This will write the statement in red text so it stands out more

Comment: Thank you! This answer did exactly what I was looking for(: